# Shortcut to get dom elements with several selectors and one class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I would like to know if something like this exists, **without filter** (I'm looking for a shortcut), with **jQuery**'s sets or **native** querySelectorAll :

```
$('(select|input[type="text"]|textarea).myCssClass')
```

I want all of select(s), input-text(s) and textarea(s) with a `myCssClass` css class.

Also I tried unsuccessfully :

```
$('(select, input[type="text"], textarea).myCssClass')
```

Notice that I'm already aware of something like:

```
$('form#myForm')
  .find('select, input[type="text"], textarea')
  .filter('.myCssClass')
  .each(....)
```

Shortcut wanted - something I would have missed reading the jQuery documentation.

Comment: No, because that's what `.filter` is for, so there doesn't need to be one.

Comment: Thanks for answer, @freedomn-m

Comment: I believe, if there was, it would be documented on the jquery selectors page: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ - it is quite comprehensive.  There might be a plugin or helper function that would make the shortcut *become* available (in the same way the `:` selectors are extensible), but not built-in to jquery directly.

Comment: `.filter(function(){return $(this).hasClass('myCssClass'))` is a very convoluted way of writing `.filter('.myCssClass')`

Comment: You're right, @04FS. In fact, it's a more complicated function in my code, I only kept its « substantifique moelle ». I correct.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such built-in method, but you can easily write a helper function to which you can pass an array of selectors that get concatenated with another selector:

```js
const combineSelectors = (applyToAll, arr) => arr
  .map(str => str + applyToAll)
  .join(',');
$(combineSelectors('.myCssClass', ['select', 'input[type="text"]', 'textarea']))
  .each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="myCssClass"></textarea><br>
<input><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text" class="myCssClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function in javascript which will accept an array of elements of and the class. Then iterate that array and use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the elements from the dom with matching class. `document.querySelectorAll` will give a collection. You can again iterate it to target each element and add class to it

```js
let className = 'myCssClass';
let elm = ['input', 'textarea'];

function addClaz(arr, className) {
  arr.forEach(function(elem) {
    document.querySelectorAll(`${elem}[class='${className}'`).forEach(function(em) {
      em.classList.add('test')
    })
  })
}
addClaz(elm, className)
```

```css
.test {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="myCssClass"></textarea><br>
<input><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text" class="myCssClass">
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I'm looking for a ***shortcut***, something I would missed reading the jQuery documentation. I can build such a function with .filter. Thanks.

Comment: @PhilippePerret not sure what exactly meant by **shortcut**

Comment: Me neither. Sorry for my bad english. I mean « a shorter way to write something long ». « $('.myClass') » is a writing shortcut for « a set of every DomElement with `myClass` css class.

Comment: @PhilippePerret: there is no shorter way than those used in the 2 answers. Why don't you accept the first answer? It certainly solves your problem!

Comment: @Meziane, it's because my way — at the end of my question — is even more shooter and clearer too. :-( (newbie) Should I answer my own question?